# moving excel file to datagridview

Tags: c#

i have excel file with 2 columns(empid,empname) ,i have to read 1st column with 8 rows then 2nd column with 8 rows ,by following code i am getting first column with 8 rows but in second column the rows or not filling insted they are filling in first column rows only . This is my code

```
             for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
             {

                 if (Cnum == 1)
                 {
                     dt.Columns.Add((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());
                     for (int Rnum = 1; Rnum <= 9; Rnum++)
                     {

                         dt.Rows.Add((ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());

                     }
                 }}
             for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
             {
                  if (Cnum == 2)
                 {

                     dt.Columns.Add((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());


                     for (int Rnum = 1; Rnum <= 9; Rnum++)
                     {
                         dt.Rows.Add((ShtRange.Cells[Rnum,2] as Excel.Range).Value2).ToString();
                     }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Wich time of excel file is?(.csv,.xls,.xlsx)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the problem is that values from the second column in excel document do not appear in the second column of `DataGridView` control. Well, the issue arises from the way you populate your grid, because what your code does is that it actually appends rows with value provided for the first column only. Here is a short solution to your problem:

```
dt.Columns.Add("c1", "First column");
dt.Columns.Add("c2", "Second column");
for (int Rnum = 1; Rnum <= 9; Rnum++)
{   
    dt.Rows.Add(
            (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString(), 
            (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());
}
```

Furthermore, you might want to create your grid structure first by adding empty rows, and after that you could populate them like this:

```
dt[Cnum - 1, Rnum - 1].Value = (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

A totally different solution is to look at the OleDbConnection provider to load the entire Excel file into a DataTable and then just bind the Datatable directly to the DataGridView.

```
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
            conn.Open();
            DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });////gets the table from the tempFile

            List<DataTable> listInnerTable = new List<DataTable>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                DataTable innerTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null, dr.ItemArray[2], null });
                listInnerTable.Add(innerTable);
            }
```

The to bind:

```
myGridView.DataSource = listInnerTable;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

This way it will work with different Excel files or new columns added to the one you are using.